# Items a to b of table in lua

Tags: lua

Is there a built in function for getting items `a` through `b` of a table? Or would I have to create one myself?

Example:
`foo = {"a", "b","c","d","e","f"}`
then I would put `foo`,`2` and `4` into the function that I am looking for and it would return `{"b","c","d"}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For extremely large sequences you will need write your own function to do this. But for most uses Lua's built in [`table.unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack) will do the trick:

```
Lua 5.4.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> t = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" }
> table.unpack(t, 2, 4)
b       c       d
```

`table.unpack` simply returns the elements of the sequence, so if you want a sequence you will need to use a table constructor:

```
> { table.unpack(t, 2, 4) }
table: 0x229d180
```

You can bind the table to a variable, or iterate over it directly:

```
> for k, v in ipairs{ table.unpack(t, 2, 4) } do
>> print(k, v)
>> end
1       b
2       c
3       d
```

Comment: is there a way to get it to return in a table though?

Comment: The second and third examples _do_ return the results in a table. The Lua REPL does not pretty-print the table, so you only see `table: 0x229d180` above; the third example with the loop iterates over that table to show its contents.